# python __detect continuous repeated string

Tags: python, duplicates, counter

I have this string

```
"hellooooo my name is ooortda boooo"

detect_rept_str("o")
```

The output will be all counts of a string which
is repeated many times consecutively.

```
all_dtct=[5,3,4]
```

`"my string".count()` is not suitable for my need.

Comment: Hey, it looks like the end word of your string should be "boooo" and not "boo0o". Am I right about this? I ask because your all_dtct=[5,3,4] looks like it corresponds to 5 o's in "hellooooo" plus 3 o's in "ooortda" plus 4 o's in "boooo". If I'm right about this being a typo, then you should correct this so that respondents can help you better.

Comment: that's by wrong ...thanks for telling ...check it again

Comment: Looks good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```py
def count_adjacent_repeats(haystack, needle):
    if '' in (haystack, needle) or needle not in haystack:
        return []

    counts = []
    for s in haystack.split(needle)[:-1]:
        if s == '':
            if counts == []:
                counts.append(0)
            counts[-1] += 1
        else:
            counts.append(1)

    return counts
```

Comment: thanks alot for the answer... I tested alot I want it to be mistaken but that was good ❤❤... without libraries 

Comment: plus can you see my question... which doesn't have any answer   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62599559/python-handle-buttons-and-tasks-of-any-program-in-windows